# Is Win32 error code 122 somewhat benign in this case?

Tags: c++, string, unicode, mfc

The following line results in `GetLastError()` return error code 122 (=ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER)

```
CString str = CString("'") + _T("%s") + CString("'");
```

But this happens only under VS2005 and doesn't happen in VS2015. Still I see no memory corruption or anything in VS2005 and the `str` variable does contain the correct value. Is that still an issue to be concerned about give the error code?

The reason this seems to happen is because of concatenation of wide character and simple character strings and the fix is to simply sorround both remaining strings with `_T("")` so the code line would look like:

```
CString str = CString(_T("'")) + _T("%s") + CString(_T("'"));
```

But what does the error code 122 really means in original line when only one string was Unicode? What wrong has really happened or is it more like a warning in this case?

Comment: Do you SetLastError(0) just before this operation?

Comment: @IgorR. No but I check the value before this call and after and it changes from 0 to 122.

Comment: Randomly calling GetLastError for things that are not documented to SetLastError on failure produces meaningless results. String concatenation such as you're doing does not result in SetLastError being called, so any value you're getting from GetLastError has no meaning.

Comment: @KenWhite For the record, I am not actually calling `GetLastError()` in code but monitoring its value through debugger.

Comment: You're still randomly monitoring the result when it is not applicable to the operation you're performing. You've not made a system call that does a SetLastError, so any result of GetLastError is meaningless. Read again what I wrote and the answer by @rodrigo below. The result of GetLastError (no matter how you're obtaining it) is worthless for the code you've posted. *I run this code and pluck a random value out of the air as an error cdoe, and the error code says this totally unrelated and non-applicable issue applies to my code. Why?*

Comment: @zar did you step into the MFC code ?

Comment: Please see [Error reporting and handling](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/winapi/2573/error-reporting-and-handling/8519/introduction#t=201609020911054612093). As a general rule, MFC never sets a thread's last error code.

Comment: The code is converting narrow strings to wide strings. The error code in question is coming from `MultiByteToWideChar()` during those conversions: "*ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER. A supplied buffer size was not large enough, or it was incorrectly set to NULL.*"  Ignore the error code.  **You** are not *directly* calling any API function, so **you** are not responsible for handling error codes.  `CString` handles that internally for you. The error code is simply not being reset before returning to your code. But your code should not care one way or the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In VS 2015 you can reproduce the error with `CString("a")` (if Unicode is set) or just `CStringW("a")`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <atlstr.h>

int main()
{
    CStringW("a");
    DWORD err = GetLastError();
    std::cout << err << "\n"; //<= error 122, ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER
    return 0;
}
```

This happens because `CString` uses WinAPI `MultiByteToWideChar` to convert ANSI `"a"` to Unicode `L"a"`. Debugging through the source code in `"atlmfc\include\cstringt.h"`, we see that at some point it calls the following function:

```
static int __cdecl GetBaseTypeLength(_In_z_ LPCSTR pszSrc) throw()
{
    // Returns required buffer size in wchar_ts
    return ::MultiByteToWideChar( _AtlGetConversionACP(), 0, pszSrc, -1, NULL, 0 )-1;
}
```

For some reason there is a `-1` at the end. I don't know why that's there, it might be necessary for other `CString` functions but in this case it ends up causing `ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER` error in the next call to `MultiByteToWideChar`. The conversion can be roughly simplified to following:

```
int main()
{
    int nDestLength = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, "a", -1, NULL, 0) - 1;
    wchar_t *pszDest = new wchar_t[32];

    //ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER occurs here because nDestLength is short by 1:
    MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, "a", -1, pszDest, nDestLength);
    DWORD err = GetLastError();
    std::cout << err << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

`nDestLength` is too small because it doesn't account for null terminator. `CString` sorts this out later but the error remains. That's a good reason not to pay attention to `GetLastError` unless the function fails.

As you noted, this error can be avoided by using the `_T` macro, because `CString` would no longer need `MultiByteToWideChar`. Or better yet, use the `L` prefix, or `CString::Format`

```
CString str = CString(L"'") + L"%s" + CString(L"'");
```

Comment: *"For some reason there is a `-1` at the end. I don't know why that's there"* - The call to `MultiByteToWideChar` returns the number of code units, including the terminating null character (when *cbMultiByte* is set to `-1`). By convention, the `CString` implementation always uses the length without the terminating null character. To account for that, the return value of `MultiByteToWideChar` needs to be adjusted.

Comment: @IInspectable But it should pass `strlen(source)` for `cbMultiByte` if it doesn't want to count the null terminator, and don't do any subtraction (for both calls to `MultiByteToWideChar`). Instead it passes -1 to get the count including the null-terminator and the two calls don't match.

Comment: `MultiByteToWideChar` doesn't need to know the number of characters ahead of time. It iterates over the entire sequence, summing up the lengths of converted code units for each character, up to and including the terminating null character. Explicitly calling `strlen` is needlessly wasting resources, for no immediate benefit.

Comment: @IInspectable If the goal is to avoid `strlen` (which is not very expensive) then it should allocate an extra byte and use `nDestLength + 1` for the second call to `MultiByteToWideChar`. Although this would complicate things even more.

Comment: The function you posted doesn't allocate any memory, and doesn't write to memory either. It's called `GetBaseTypeLength`, and that's what it does. You can't do any better than the implementation does. Whether `strlen` is expensive or not doesn't make a difference. It's not needed, and always wastes resources.

Comment: If you are referring to the actual conversion (paraphrased in your [mcve]): There are only 2 reasons to pass an explicit *cbMultiByte* argument: `1` The source string is not zero terminated, and `2` the source string contains embedded NUL characters. Neither is the case, and passing `-1` for *cbMultiByte* is the correct usage. The only benefit to calling `strlen` and passing an explicit *cbMultiByte* argument would be to not set the last-error code. The implementation would thus meet a specification it never promised to meet.

Comment: Your proposed solution to pass `nDestLength + 1` for the *cchWideChar* parameter is a bug waiting to happen. What if the final character to be converted requires not 1, but 2 code units? Should the call succeed? Or fail? None of your proposed changes make for a better implementation.

Comment: @IInspectable How would you write this conversion yourself? Let's say we have the strange requirement that the destination string should not be null-terminated, and we are starting with `CStringW("a")` (the length of input buffer is not supplied). Note, in my version `MultiByteToWideChar` returns zero (failure) in addition to setting `GetLastError`. It doesn't really matter though, there is an easy solution `CStringW(L"a")`...

Comment: The requirement isn't, that your destination string should not be zero-terminated. The requirement is, to have it zero-terminated exactly once. To meet this requirement, conversion and zero-termination are distinct steps in the initialization. Zero-termination is also performed for object constructions that do not involve character encoding conversions. *"[T]here is an easy solution `CStringW(L"a")`"* - That's true only, if you are construction from literals. Sometimes you need to convert from dynamic ANSI/MBCS strings as well, and then it does matter.

Comment: *"Note, in my version `MultiByteToWideChar` returns zero (failure) in addition to setting `GetLastError`"* - That's irrelevant. You already know that the call will succeed, since you just verified that by having it calculate the required destination buffer size.

Answer (score 4):

`GetLastError()` is only meaningful after some system call has returned an error. Since your code does not have any system call, `GetLastError()` can return anything.

Maybe the value you see is the last error from the last system call that failed. Or maybe it is some error that happened from inside the `CString` class, but it is handled there.

TL;DR; No error here.

Comment: I can assure the error code does get generated because this line I posted. I created a new default application with nothing else in it and added a button and this call in button click event and I see the error code 122. So onething is sure, there is no other system call.

Comment: @zar: you added a button? So there is a window and a window class and a mesaage loop somewhere, maybe in the MFC library or similar. A lot of system calls in there.

Comment: @zar I can assure you that the error code was set by some implementation detail and handled by the implementation if necessary.  Unless CString itself documents that you should look at GetLastError() after using it (and it doesn't), you should ignore it.

Comment: *"`GetLastError()` is only meaningful after some system call has returned an error."* - That's not what the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679360.aspx) says: *"Most functions that set the thread's last-error code set it when they fail. **However, some functions also set the last-error code when they succeed.**"*

Comment: @IInspectable: Well, yes, I was simplifying a bit. There are even functions that you don't know if they failed until you call `GetLastError`. That's why you sometimes hear the advice to call `SetLastError(0)` before.

Comment: There is no need to simplify anything (all the more, since you got it wrong). The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679360.aspx) already put it the most simplistic way: *"You should call the GetLastError function immediately when a function's return value indicates that such a call will return useful data."* This differs from your version in two key points: `1` It spells out, when to call it (*"immediately"*), and `2` it accurately names the predicate (*"when a function's return value indicates it"*). Don't make a simple statement simpler (and wrong).